# Передача переменной js в разные текстовые поля

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт который передает переменную в текстовое поле

```
<script>
function HandlePopupResult(result) {
document.getElementById("mytext").value = result;
}
</script>  

<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
```

Как можно передать эту же самую переменную в другое текстовое поле? Пробовал с одинаковыми id, но не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function HandlePopupResult(result) {
 var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("mytext");
 if (inputs)
 {
  for (var i in inputs)
  {
   inputs[i].value = result;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<textarea class="mytext"></textarea><br>
<textarea class="mytext"></textarea><br>
<input type="text" class="mytext" /><br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="HandlePopupResult('some text')" />
```